# Homeomorphism between a manifold minus distinct points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold and $p,p' \in M$, $U, U'$ be coordinate balls in $M$ containing $p,p'$ respectively. Then how can we find a homeomorphism $F:M -\{p\} \to M - \{p'\}$ and a loop $f:I \to U$ such that $[f]$ generates $\pi_1(U-p)$ and $[F\circ f]$ generates $\pi_1(U'-p')$?

I can think of a homeomorphism between $U-p$ and $U' - p'$ by composing the coordinate maps with the translation map in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that moves the unit circle with center $p$ to the unit circle with center $p'$. I believe this map composed with the loop that generates the fundamental group of a punctured disk will do the job. However, I cannot figure out how this homeomorphism can be extended in to the whole manifold minus a point. How could we extend this map?

Comment: Every connected manifold $M$ is $k$-homogeneous for each positive integer $k$, i.e., for any two sets $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ and $\{y_1,...,y_k\}$ of points of  $M$ we have a homeomorphism $f\colon M\to M$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1,...,f(x_k)=y_k$. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3893479/existence-of-a-self-homeomorphism-phi-of-a-connected-hausdorff-manifold-satis/3893501#3893501

Comment: @User Those results are for connected manifolds. Here I am asking how to extend it in the case of a connected manifold minus a point, which may not be connected.

Comment: Puncturing an $n$-manifold, where $n\geq 2$, at a point doesn't change the connectedness.